# 403 Forbidden: Nginx not serving statics in Django Admin panel

Tags: python, css, django, nginx, django-admin

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'adminstatic')
```

mynginx.conf     `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mynginx.conf`
you can be sure that I have only this conf file in sites-enabled folder

```
server {
    listen                *:80;
    server_name           _;
    access_log            /var/log/myapp.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/myapp.error.log;

    # Django media

   location /static/ {
     alias /root/proj/myapp/adminstatic/; #your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass    unix:/tmp/myapp.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }

}
```

after this I tried collectstatic command
`python manage.py collectstatic` 
It has succesfully collected all the statics in adminstatic folder.I crosscheked, there is a folder named `admin` in adminstatic folder. and this admin folder has 3 folders named `css`,`img`,`js`.

all these I'm doing in production machine. so when I tried to access the django admin page on my local browser by production's ip, the admin panel is opening but with loading any css/js. I did F12 and see in network tab. there was forbidden error for all statics.

PS: I'm using uWsgi along with nginx.

and as usual I've already looked at few SO threads and blogs. but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nginx web process user (usually `www-data`) probably doesn't have read permission of `/root/proj/myapp/adminstatic/`.  I imagine if you check your `myapp.error.log` you would see permission denied messages.

You'd need to move your project into a folder the nginx process has permission to read from (you really shouldn't serve these things from `/root`) or you could `chown` / `chmod` `/root/proj/myapp/adminstatic/` appropriately to give access to `www-data`.

Comment: Even if you `chmod 777 -R adminstatic` the permission of `/root` still won't allow you to access those files- which is why you shouldn't serve those files from `/root`.  You can test this by trying to read `adminstatic` from another account on the machine.  You'll get `Permission denied`.

Comment: Either modify permission of `/root` to `drwxr-xr-x` (generally not a good idea) or move the project out of `/root` to a folder that can be accessed by `www-data`.

Comment: My guess is that you are probably also running uwsgi as root which is a pretty terrible idea- if someone compromises the web app they have rooted your entire system.

Answer (score 1):

I moved my static files to /data/www and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Move your project to `/var/www/html/`then run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data project-directory/` .Remember to edit your configurations on `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-project.conf` to pint to the new location.

Then run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload, 
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn, 
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```